# Celery worker processes django task but does not execute

Tags: django, celery

I am a beginner. I have a django project in which I am trying to add a functionality where I send a welcome email when a user signs up.

I am using the django development server on 127.0.0.1:8000, a celery worker, and a docker container running redis on redis://127.0.0.1:6379. When I sign up a test user, no welcome email prints to the console (current email config is `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`
so that would be the expected result.

Contents of my tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def send_welcome_email(user_email):
    print("send welcome email started")
    subject = 'Welcome to My Website'
    message = 'Thank you for registering at My Website!'
    from_email = 'noreply@mywebsite.com'
    recipient_list = [user_email]
    print(f"Sending email to {user_email}")

    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
    print("Email sent")
```

I have done necessary configuration such as adding the celery app to my project's **init**.py, adding Celery settings (broker URL and result backend), a celery.py file in my django project, and I have also confirmed that Celery is connected to my redis database.

When I check the status of the task with Flower, I see that a Celery worker has received the task, and it is listed under 'Processed', but does not move to Failed or Succeeded, and as stated, no email prints to console.

As connections seem to be normal and celery is not overburdened, I do not understand what is causing my tasks to not be executed. Using the project shell to manually call the task `result = send_welcome_email.delay('test@gmail.com')` gives the same result, but calling the task without .delay() prints to console. Struggling to identify the issue.

Celery log:

```
 -------------- celery@POLARBY v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0 2023-09-06 01:06:38
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         Kemestra:0x2158f8da190
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . account.tasks.send_welcome_email
  . account.tasks.simple_task

[2023-09-06 01:06:38,480: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0

[2023-09-06 01:06:38,488: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,803: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 15324 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,805: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 5212 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,812: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 16680 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,813: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 14388 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,814: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 1040 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,815: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 352 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,817: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 15132 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,830: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 8304 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,835: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 6444 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,843: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 17908 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,850: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 9556 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:38,875: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 11840 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:39,474: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 5108 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:39,474: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 8028 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:06:39,519: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-09-06 01:06:39,540: INFO/MainProcess] celery@POLARBY ready.
[2023-09-06 01:06:39,966: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 17104 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:07:10,515: INFO/MainProcess] Task account.tasks.send_welcome_email[40528b4a-46ca-45b1-8345-642883695b0a] received
[2023-09-06 01:07:10,954: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-18] child process 6648 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:07:10,955: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-17] child process 18112 calling self.run()
[2023-09-06 01:07:10,955: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 15540 calling self.run()
```

and et cetera

Comment: I know that issue is with celery, but can you send email without celery? maybe the sending email part itself is misconfigured.

Comment: Yes, calling the email function in the shell without the .delay immediately prints to console.

Comment: did you try to wrap the function in a try/catch and print error message if found any?

Comment: Fixed it by starting the worker with the `-P solo` setting added onto the end. So line looked like `celery -A django_project worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=10 -n worker1 -P solo`.